Try to include <torch/torch.h> -- Always reporting error
I want to #include <torch/torch.h> in C++ env of VS Code.
My try



I tried to use absolute include path:



#include <C:/Users/Felix/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Lib/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/torch.h>

But got error:
In file included from try.cpp:6:
C:/Users/Felix/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Lib/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/torch.h:3:10: fatal error: torch/all.h: No such file or directory
 #include <torch/all.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.




Also tried configure to the .vscode/c_cpp_properties.json:



"includePath": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
    "C:/Users/Felix/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Lib/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include",
    "D:/develop/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include",
    "D:/develop/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include-fixed"
]

Still got the same error.



If only use #include <torch/torch.h> with json config



Got error:
PS D:\VS CODE\FlashAttentionV2> cd "d:\VS CODE\FlashAttentionV2\" ; if ($?) { g++ try.cpp -o try } ; if ($?) { .\try }
try.cpp:6:10: fatal error: torch/torch.h: No such file or directory
 #include <torch/torch.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.




Tried -I with json config and absolute path include:



PS D:\VS CODE\FlashAttentionV2> g++ -I "C:\Users\Felix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\torch\include\torch\" try.cpp

Got same error in 1.
My system
My code runs in windows 11:

AMD Ryzen 7 5800H with Radeon Graphics  3.20 GH
OS: 22631.3593

My file locate in D:\VS CODE\FlashAttentionV2\try.cpp
I tried to google these things, but didn't find more solutions. If you can help me to figure what to do next, thank you very much!!
I have included these things in the details of the problem.

c_cpp_properties.json is for Intellisense. You need to add the include path to tasks.json. The path you used in the 4th example may be incomplete. You need -I "C:/Users/Felix/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Lib/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include" if the path used in your other examples is correct.
